# Significance of common schema - MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

Why common schema is not available in MySQL 5.6? What is the significance of it? So If there is a need for common schema for an application, what is the workaround to have common schema in 5.6 or should I go back to 5.5?

Also, Can I download the common_schema from code google and install it in 5.6? Are there any implications as such?

Answer (score 0):

Shlomi Noach's Common_Schema is mostly stored procedures; most of the code should work in most versions of MySQL/MariaDB. It is a set of nifty tools that he [freely provides](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema) to anyone. Use them if you want. (Some are more useful than others.)

Oracle neither invented them, nor purchased them, so it does not come with Oracle's 5.6. It's not quite the same flavor as the Percona Toolkit, which is an even more vital set of tools. Again, not Oracle, but easily downloaded. That Toolkit probably comes with Percona's 5.6. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876